# MySQL DELETE query with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table PEOPLE, with columns 'firstName' 'lastName'  (varchars) and 'deleted' (bit) amongst others.

I want to delete from this table, entries that have the property TRUE for deleted, but only if they share their exact firstName and lastName with another, separate, entry in the table.

In other words, remove from the table 'deleted' people, but only if they are a duplicate.

Not sure how to do this, and especially not how to do it quickly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How can you tell which is duplicate and which is primary record?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate Entries in DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970329/duplicate-entries-in-db)

Comment: All fields are in the same table?

Comment: @Antonio: All fields are in the same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM people
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM people p2
    WHERE people.firstName = p2.firstName AND people.lastName = p2.lastName
    GROUP BY firstName, lastName
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
AND deleted = 1 -- True
```

Comment: do you need the where clause in the nested statement?

Comment: Yes, to join the subquery with the outer table.

Comment: @niktrs, this will take a loooong time is the table is huge.

Comment: won't this query delete all entries that have deleted = 1?

Comment: We are asked "I want to delete from this table, entries that have the property TRUE for deleted, but only if they share their exact firstName and lastName with another", so we want deleted=1 and every lastName, firstName count > 1

Comment: @Neal maybe you are right about performance. I would also suggest to you the use of DISTINCT since usually it performs better than GROUP BY

Comment: @niktrs this does take some time, but it seems to work. Thanks

Comment: @Yottagray Potential problems: first, if there are two different people named "John Smith" in the database and one of their records is marked "deleted," he is gone. Second, even if you only have one "John Smith" in the database and he has two records but **both** are marked deleted=1, then it will delete both of them (not necessarily keep one of them around)! Maybe these aren't important to you.

Comment: @Chris No this is important for me to know, I will have to keep this in mind as I work forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a unique primary key (... will depend on design...), then this is a viable alternative to needing to count the occurrances of entries:

```
DELETE FROM people as A
WHERE deleted = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
            FROM people as B
            WHERE B.id <> A.id
            AND A.firstName = B.firstName
            AND A.lastName = B.lastName)
```

This may have slightly better performance than counting rows.  Please note that this query will likely suffer the same possible issue present in the previous answer; specifically, if there are two or more 'deleted' rows, and no 'non-deleted', both of them will probably be removed (leaving you with no rows!).  If the intent of the query is only to remove 'deleted' rows when there is a 'non-deleted' equivalent row, add `AND B.deleted = 0` as part of the inner `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Great -- this one allows an easy `AND B.deleted = 0` fix that I suspect the questioner wants, where the other doesn't.

Comment: Suggestion: Use A.id>B.id, so everything newer than the first record will be deleted. Also performs faster.

Comment: @niktrs - Unfortunately, that presumes that only later (or earlier) ids are ever 'deleted'.  Depending on design and use, this assumption may or may not be valid.  
But yes, otherwise, that would likely perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rudimentary way of doing it:

http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/12/12/remove-duplicate-entries-rows-a-mysql-database-table/

Basically:
1.  Create a new table with `GROUP BY`.
2.  Delete old table.
3.  Rename new table.